# Building the R package, "later," generates undefined symbol

Tags: r, undefined, symbols

Updating installed packages for R-3.5.2 (in Slackware-14.2) the "later" package fails to load because of this error:

```
/usr/lib/R/library/later/libs/later.so: undefined symbol: __atomic_fetch_add_8,
```

Web searches and folks on the r-help mail list were not able to resolve this issue.

Earlier versions of "later" had no problems installing and updating.

All suggestions will be followed up.

Comment: Have you tried to install the developper version using devtools? `devtools::install_github("r-lib/devtools")`

Comment: devtools are installed here. So far I've not found a package requiring 'later' so I'm ignoring it. I'll deal with that package if/when I need to do so. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

Issue [#73](https://github.com/r-lib/later/issues/73) on github discusses that on some platforms, one needs to add a flag `-latomic` even though `std::atomic` is part of the C++11 standard library.

Assuming you have C++11 installed on your Slackware 14.2, you should be able to:

```
git clone https://github.com/r-lib/later.git
nano later/src/Makevars # or whatever editor you prefer
# Change `PKG_LIBS = -pthread` to `PKG_LIBS = -pthread -latomic`
sudo R CMD INSTALL later
```

**Update December 2019:**

With the latest version of later, it now is:

```
git clone https://github.com/r-lib/later.git
nano later/src/Makevars.in # or whatever editor you prefer
# Change `PKG_LIBS = -pthread @extra_pkg_libs@` to `PKG_LIBS = -pthread -latomic @extra_pkg_libs@`
sudo R CMD INSTALL later
```